# Why do netsh ip delete commands run so slowly in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: networking, command-line, windows-server-2003, netsh

So a coworker accidentally added an entire /20 (~4000 ips) to a Windows 2003 Server.

I generated a simple batch file with all the necessary lines to remove these IPs. The commands do work and remove the IPs as I want, but the problem is they take around 3 to 10 minutes to execute each line, and the CPU is staying > 90% utilization, svchost.exe and lsass.exe seem to be eating up the most cycles.

Anyone know why these netsh commands are taking so long to execute?

Example:

> netsh interface ip delete address name="Local Area Connection" addr=10.10.150.24

Answer (score -1):

Clear all ip settings:

```
netsh interface ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
```

It del all IP address. If the server is remote, then I recommend that you configure the DHCP server will assign your server.

When you run the `netsh interface ip ...` command, it rewrites two registry keys that are used by TCP/IP.

```
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\ 
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DHCP\Parameters\
```

Apparently it takes a while.